# Как отсортировать коллекцию без использования вспомогательных коллекций по пяти условиям

Tags: java, коллекции, compare

Есть код:

```
package main.comparator;

public class CarForSort implements Comparable {
    private String color;
    private String bodyStyle;
    private String Make;
    private String Model;
    private Integer year;

    public CarForSort(String color, String bodyStyle, String make, String model, int year) {
        this.color = color;
        this.bodyStyle = bodyStyle;
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getBodyStyle() {
        return bodyStyle;
    }

    public void setBodyStyle(String bodyStyle) {
        this.bodyStyle = bodyStyle;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return Make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        Make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return Model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        Model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

и

```
package main.comparator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarForSort first = new CarForSort("orange", "coupe",
                "bmw", "3", 1992);
        CarForSort second = new CarForSort("black", "cabriolet",
                "bmw", "6", 2008);
        CarForSort third = new CarForSort("black", "hatchback",
                "opel", "astra", 2000);
        CarForSort fourth = new CarForSort("red", "suv",
                "mercedes", "ml", 1992);
        CarForSort fifth = new CarForSort("blue", "sedan",
                "kia", "rio", 2008);
        CarForSort sixth = new CarForSort("gray", "sedan",
                "tesla", "moles3", 2019);
        CarForSort seventh = new CarForSort("red", "sedan",
                "tesla", "model_s", 2019);
        CarForSort eigth = new CarForSort("green", "sedan",
                "bmw", "5", 1993);
        CarForSort ninth = new CarForSort("orange", "sedan",
                "bmw", "7", 1994);
        CarForSort tenth = new CarForSort("blue", "coupe",
                "bmw", "6", 2001);
        CarForSort eventh = new CarForSort("red", "sedan",
                "bmw", "3", 1998);
        CarForSort twelwth = new CarForSort("orange", "sedan",
                "bmw", "7", 1997);
        CarForSort thirteenth = new CarForSort("blue", "sedan",
                "opel", "omega", 2000);
        CarForSort fourteenth = new CarForSort("orange", "white",
                "opel", "vectra", 1999);
        CarForSort fiftenth = new CarForSort("black", "coupe",
                "kia", "stinger", 2019);
        CarForSort sixteenth = new CarForSort("orange", "sedan",
                "bmw", "7", 2017);
        CarForSort seventeenth = new CarForSort("orange", "coupe",
                "bmw", "3", 1992);
        CarForSort eighteenth = new CarForSort("orange", "coupe",
                "bmw", "6", 2014);
        CarForSort opel = new CarForSort("orange", "coupe",
                "astra", "4", 1998);

        List<CarForSort> notSort = new ArrayList<>();
        notSort.add(first);
        notSort.add(second);
        notSort.add(third);
        notSort.add(fourth);
        notSort.add(fifth);
        notSort.add(sixth);
        notSort.add(seventh);
        notSort.add(eigth);
        notSort.add(ninth);
        notSort.add(tenth);
        notSort.add(eventh);
        notSort.add(twelwth);
        notSort.add(thirteenth);
        notSort.add(fourteenth);
        notSort.add(fiftenth);
        notSort.add(sixteenth);
        notSort.add(seventh);
        notSort.add(eighteenth);
        notSort.add(opel);
        notSort.add(seventeenth);

        List<CarForSort> firstSort = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CarForSort> secondSort = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CarForSort> thirdSort = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CarForSort> fourthSort = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CarForSort> fifthSort = new ArrayList<>();

        for (CarForSort car : notSort) {
            if (car.getMake().equals("bmw") && car.getColor().equals("orange")) {
                firstSort.add(car);
                continue;
            }

            if (car.getMake().equals("opel") && car.getColor().equals("black")) {
                secondSort.add(car);
                continue;
            }

            if (car.getMake().equals("opel") && car.getBodyStyle().equals("sedan")) {
                thirdSort.add(car);
                continue;
            }

            if (car.getMake().equals("tesla") && car.getColor().equals("moles3")) {
                fourthSort.add(car);
                continue;
            }

            fifthSort.add(car);
        }

        List<CarForSort> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.addAll(firstSort
                .stream()
                .sorted(CarForSort::compareTo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        result.addAll(secondSort
                .stream()
                .sorted(CarForSort::compareTo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        result.addAll(thirdSort
                .stream()
                .sorted(CarForSort::compareTo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        result.addAll(fourthSort
                .stream()
                .sorted(CarForSort::compareTo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        result.addAll(fifthSort
                .stream()
                .sorted(CarForSort::compareTo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        result.forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e.getMake() + " " + e.getModel() + " " + e.getColor() + " " + e.getBodyStyle() + " " + e.getYear());
        });
    }
}
```

Логика следующая из не отсортированной коллекции, по каждому условию добавляются в определенную коллекцию, затем каждая коллекция сортируется по году и добавляется в конечную. Код полностью рабочий но можно ли как то сделать это без помощи вспомогательных коллекций, к примеру использую компаратор, если да то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше количество кода просто убивает... Ваш код полностью рабочий, только работает он некорректно. По году у вас сортировка не производится, хотя в стримах вы вызываете метод compareTo для каждой коллекции (ваш метод compareTo всегда возвращает 0, что означает равность переменных в любом случае, сортировка не происходит). И почему вы не типизируете интерфейс Comparable, когда имплементируете его, разве вы не видите, что он с дженериком? По этой причине в метод compareTo  вам прилетает object вместо желаемого для сортировки CarForSort. Мало того, в 4-ой коллекции вы сравниваете moles3 с цветом. Исходя из того, что вы добавляете в коллекцию, moles3 - не цвет, а модель. Ваше условие никогда не срабатывает и поэтому 4-ая коллекция всегда будет пустой.
Если это исправит и переписать с компаратором, то выглядит это примерно так (метод compareTo  можно еще отрефакторить, но просто нет времени):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        final List<CarForSort> notSort = new ArrayList<>();
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "coupe", "bmw", "3", 1992));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("black", "cabriolet", "bmw", "6", 2008));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("black", "hatchback", "opel", "astra", 2000));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("red", "suv", "mercedes", "ml", 1992));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("blue", "sedan", "kia", "rio", 2008));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("gray", "sedan", "tesla", "moles3", 2019));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("red", "sedan", "tesla", "model_s", 2019));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("green", "sedan", "bmw", "5", 1993));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "sedan", "bmw", "7", 1994));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("blue", "coupe", "bmw", "6", 2001));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("red", "sedan", "bmw", "3", 1998));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "sedan", "bmw", "7", 1997));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("blue", "sedan", "opel", "omega", 2000));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "white", "opel", "vectra", 1999));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("black", "coupe", "kia", "stinger", 2019));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "sedan", "bmw", "7", 2017));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "coupe", "bmw", "3", 1992));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "coupe", "bmw", "6", 2014));
        notSort.add(new CarForSort("orange", "coupe", "astra", "4", 1998));         
        notSort.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class CarForSort implements Comparable <CarForSort> {

    private final String color;
    private final String bodyStyle;
    private final String make;
    private final String model;
    private final Integer year;

    public CarForSort(String color, String bodyStyle, String make, String model, int year) {
        this.color = color;
        this.bodyStyle = bodyStyle;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getBodyStyle() {
        return bodyStyle;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return make + " " + model + " " + color + " " + bodyStyle + " " + year;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CarForSort car) {
        int comp1 = pairComparing(this, ()->this.getColor(), car, ()->car.getColor(), "bmw", "orange");
        if (comp1 != 0) return comp1;
        comp1 = pairComparing(this, ()->this.getColor(), car, ()->car.getColor(), "opel", "black");
        if (comp1 != 0) return comp1;
        comp1 = pairComparing(this, ()->this.getBodyStyle(), car, ()->car.getBodyStyle(), "opel", "sedan");
        if (comp1 != 0) return comp1;
        comp1 = pairComparing(this, ()->this.getModel(), car, ()->car.getModel(), "tesla", "moles3");
        if (comp1 != 0) return comp1;        
        return this.year-car.getYear();
    }

    private int pairComparing (CarForSort car1, Supplier <String> getter1, 
            CarForSort car2, Supplier <String> getter2, String make, String param){
        int car1Comp=0, car2Comp=0;
        if (car1.getMake().equals(make) && getter1.get().equals(param)) car1Comp=1;
        if (car2.getMake().equals(make) && getter2.get().equals(param)) car2Comp=1;
        if (car1Comp==1 && car2Comp==1) return car1.getYear()-car2.getYear();
        return car2Comp-car1Comp;
    }

}
```